# SQL Server : joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to join two tables together to display the information in the following way.

```
ServerName DatabaseName MessageText RestoreTime BackupTime Servername
```

However I am running into a problem, I am getting multiple records. The result should only show 31 records however I am getting 961 records. I believe that I did not write the following script correctly and would appreciate some help with it.

```
select * 
from 
    (SELECT 
         ServerName, DatabaseName, MessageText,
         [datetime] as RestoreTime 
     FROM 
         [dbo].[CheckDBHist]
     WHERE 
         datetime < (SELECT getdate()) 
         AND datetime > (SELECT getdate() - 1) 
         AND ServerName = 'servername' 
    ) allnames
inner join
    (select 
         BackupStartDate, ServerName
     from [dbo].[DBBackupFileDate]
     where BackupStartDate < (SELECT getdate()) 
       and BackupStartDate > (SELECT getdate()-1)
    ) servern on servern.ServerName = allnames.ServerName
order by 
    RestoreTime desc
```

Comment: 31*31=961. Check your `join` condition. I think you are getting a cross joined result.

Comment: `The result should only show 31` why is it so? On my data it should show 123456789 rows

Comment: Yes, I see where the 961 is coming from, I am just not sure how to fix it. I started using tsql a few weeks ago and I am still learning. Would you be able to provide me an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Yes, I see where the 961 is coming from, I am just not sure how to fix it. I started using tsql a few weeks ago and I am still learning. Would you be able to provide me an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: i guess you should also `join` on the dates from your derived tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    ServerName, DatabaseName, MessageText, [datetime] as RestoreTime 
FROM
    [dbo].[CheckDBHist] dbhist
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[DBBackupFileDate] bckpdate ON dbhist.ServerName = bckpdate.ServerName
WHERE 
    dbhist.datetime < (SELECT getdate()) AND 
    dbhist.datetime > (SELECT getdate()-1) AND
    ServerName = 'servername' AND 
    bckpdate.BackupStartDate < (SELECT getdate()) AND   
    bckpdate.BackupStartDate > (SELECT getdate()-1) 
ORDER BY 
    dbhist.RestoreTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! You all gave me some good ideas to work with!

Answer (score 0):

I run a similar report from time to time to get DB info as well as last backup date.  Try this

```
WITH cte_MostRecent
AS
(
SELECT sdb.Name AS DatabaseName, MAX(bus.backup_finish_date) MostRecentBkp
FROM    sys.sysdatabases sdb
        LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bus ON bus.database_name = sdb.name
WHERE bus.type = 'D' --full
GROUP BY sdb.name
),
    cte_EndDate
AS
(
SELECT p.name DatabaseName, MAX(p.backup_finish_date) EndDate
FROM cte_MostRecent mr
    LEFT JOIN  ( SELECT sdb.name, bus.backup_finish_date
                 FROM    sys.sysdatabases sdb
                        LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bus ON bus.database_name = sdb.name 
                 WHERE bus.type = 'D'
                ) p ON p.name = mr.DatabaseName AND p.backup_finish_date < mr.MostRecentBkp
GROUP BY p.name
)
SELECT mf.DatabaseName, mf.TotalSizeMB, mf.TotalSizeGB
     , COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), MAX(p.StartDate), 121), '-') AS StartDate
     , COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), ed.EndDate, 121), '-') AS EndDate
     , DATEDIFF(hh,MAX(p.StartDate),ed.EndDate) BackupInterval_Hours
FROM
(SELECT  DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName
      , SUM((size*8)/1024.00) TotalSizeMB
      , SUM((size*8)/1024)/1024.00 TotalSizeGB
 FROM sys.master_files
 GROUP BY database_id) mf
    LEFT JOIN cte_EndDate ed ON ed.DatabaseName = mf.DatabaseName
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  sdb.Name AS DatabaseName, bus.backup_finish_date StartDate
                FROM    sys.sysdatabases sdb
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bus ON bus.database_name = sdb.name
                WHERE bus.type = 'D' --full
               ) p ON p.DatabaseName = mf.DatabaseName AND p.StartDate < ed.EndDate 
GROUP BY mf.DatabaseName, mf.TotalSizeMB, mf.TotalSizeGB, ed.EndDate    
ORDER BY mf.TotalSizeMB DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

### Hi can you please try the below query

```
select * from (SELECT checkHist.ServerName servername, checkHist.DatabaseName, checkHist.MessageText, checkHist.[datetime] as RestoreTime ,bkFileDate.BackupStartDate bkstartDate 
    FROM [dbo].[CheckDBHist] checkHist inner join [dbo].[DBBackupFileDate]  bkFileDate on bkFileDate.ServerName = checkHist.ServerName) allnames 
where (RestoreTime < (SELECT getdate()) 
and datetime > (SELECT getdate()-1)) 
and (bkstartDate < (SELECT getdate()) 
and bkstartDate > (SELECT getdate()-1)) 
and servername = 'servername' 
order by RestoreTime desc
```